# Contacts->New Email fails when sending to more than one contact after upgrade to 5.35.1 (Wordpress)

Tags: civimail, upgrade

Salut. We recently upgraded to Civicrm 5.35.1 (Wordpress). When we try to send Emails to more than one recipient in Contacts->New Email, the operation fails (see screenshot attached). One recipient works fine. When I use one recipient and add the rest via CC or BCC, it works as well, but in this case tokens are ignored, won't work. Before the upgrade (5.25), we just added all Names in the top field and never used CC or BCC. Does anybody have similar experiences? I also attached the last lines in the logfile in ConfigandLog

[image: error message]

```
 Apr 05 11:32:27  [warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)


Apr 05 11:48:09  [info] Report Error Extension could not send since no email address was set.

Apr 05 11:48:09  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "In ihrer Anfrage ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#25149
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "In ihrer Anfrage ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Form/Optout.php"
    #line: 37
    trace: {
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Form/Optout.php:37 {
        › if (!$q) {
        ›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception(ts("There was an error in your request"));
        › }
      }
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:608 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:76 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:347 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:285 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:68 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1172 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:354 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:292 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:316 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php:551 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php:763 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/functions.php:1291 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-blog-header.php:16 { …}
      /home/gemeingut/www/www/index.php:17 { …}
    }
  }
]


Apr 05 11:48:09  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(433): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1172): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(354): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#4 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))
#5 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#6 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(551): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#7 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php(763): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#8 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-includes/functions.php(1291): WP->main("")
#9 /home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#10 /home/gemeingut/www/www/index.php(17): require("/home/gemeingut/www/www/wp-blog-header.php")
#11 {main}


Apr 05 12:47:23  [warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)
```

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce... I just sent a test email via Civi 5.35.1 to two recipients added to the "To:" field (not cc: or bcc:). Did not use any tokens. The email was sent and received successfully by both recipients. Running WP 5.4.4.

Comment: I think the issue is coming from an extension you have installed.   are you running the latest of net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/ (ie from github since it looks like releases haven't been dropped for a long time)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I manually updated all extensions just now (including net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/), unfortunately the malfunction persists. It also persists when I deactivate every single extension.

Comment: We are having a similar issue on Drupal - to replicate the error (in Drupal) there needs to be greater than 2 recipients plus an attachment. 2 recipients with an attachment works, as does multiple recipients with no attachment. This was replicated on 2 different sites using different SMTP providers (1 our server, the other CiviSMTP). The PDF tested is only 13kb so would not have hit any size limitations even multiplied by the number of recipients.
We tested by viewing the contacts of a group and using the action "Email - send now (to 50 or less)"

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2588

Comment: I don't think 2588 is the same issue because 2588 started in 5.36.0. Also the log posted here seems to be about a bulk mailing even though the post suggests it was a regular email.

Comment: The issue in 2588 is fixed in 5.37.0